# Render multiple includes in json with rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, model, include

I have this code that renders a variable vacancy with a custom serializer and also is included a restaurant as part of my model.

```
vacancy = Vacancy.find(params[:id])
render json: vacancy, 
       serializer: VacancyDetailSerializer,
       include: [:restaurant]
```

The thing is that I want to include multiple objects and render, something like this:

```
vacancy = Vacancy.find(params[:id])
render json: vacancy, 
       serializer: VacancyDetailSerializer,
       include: [:restaurant, :total_vacancies]
```

In `:total_vacancies` I want to send `Vacancy.count`, but I don't know if I have to make it by serializers, or in the include, or how to do it.

As I know, I just only need to put a comma after the object and then specify the other object in the included but is not working.

**Update**

P.D. total_vacancies is not a table, is a method from my model of Vacancy

P.D.2. it's true that if I put `total_vacancies` as an attribute in my serializer will work, but if I do that everytime I render this json it will repeat the `total_vacancies` every time I call a vacancy, for example, imagine that I have 100 vacancies, then my json will write all the parameters that I have from my vacancy and the `total_vacancies` 100 times instead of 1 time as a different object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume TotalVacancies is another table.

You need to have separate serializer for each one and `VacancyDetailSerializer` must be modified like below

if TotalVacancies is not a separate table. If TotalVacancies is not a separate table then use the `has_many` which i commented below and use its corresponding Serializer: `TotalVacanciesSerializer`

```
class VacancyDetailSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  attributes :total_vacancies

  #has_many :total_vacancies
  has_one :restaurant     

  def total_vacancies
   self.object.count
  end
end


# total_vacancies_serializer.rb
class TotalVacanciesSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

end

# restaurant_serializer.rb
class RestaurantSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

end
```

You dont need to include like this in render. Since we have added in VacanciesSerializer below code should itself include TotalVacancies and Restaurant

Also you can control the list of attributes in Restaurant and TotalVacancies

```
vacancy = Vacancy.find(params[:id])
render json: vacancy, 
       serializer: VacancyDetailSerializer
```

Comment: Okey, I tried that way, but a little thing that I didn't mention is that I don't want to send the `total_vacancies` multiple times because if I put the method in the serializer will work, but imagine that I have 100 vacancies, then the `total_vacancies` will repeat as attribute 100 times, and I just want it to be 1 time, that's why I want it to put it as an include of another object or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution given by Ian Lewis on Facebook:**

Just simply put

```
render json: { vacancy: vacancy, vacancy_count: Vacancy.count }
```

And then everything works perfectly, the final code was like this:

```
render json: { vacancy: vacancy, vacancy_count: Vacancy.count },
             each_serializer: VacancyDetailSerializer,
             include: [:restaurant]
```

*Source:*

https://www.facebook.com/groups/railsrocks/permalink/10151113078349957/?comment_id=10151113264214957&reply_comment_id=10151113313639957&notif_id=1535830677954887&notif_t=group_comment